# divs are not aligned in the same row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap layout problem which I couldn't figured out how to solve.

On my page, I present 6 recent cars and on the desktop view, I would like to have 3 cars per row so each of the car reside inside a bootstrap div container:**col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12**

Car images are responsive. Although resized images sizes are identical, if the original resolutions of the cars are slightly different, my desktop layout is distorted as you can see below.

[image]

Below you can see the html & css code

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Section Header -->
<div class="section-header">
  <h3>Son Eklenen Arabalar</h3>
  <p>Farklı bütçe ve ihtiyaçlara göre zengin araba seçeneklerimizi görmek için, satılık araçlar bağlatısına tıklayabilirsiniz. Aşağıda son eklenen araçlarımızdan kısaca örnekleri görmektesiniz.</p>
</div><!-- Section Header /- -->

<!-- Row -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 inventroy-box">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Car" class="item">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2016-audi-a3-a3-sedan-1-6-tdi-sport-line-dizel-otomatik-beyaz-379" title="2016 Audi A3İncele">
        <img itemprop="image" src="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/otogallery/store_logos/thumb/5244/_MG_0230.jpg?1523107625" alt="sahibinden satılık araba 2016 Audi A3 A3 Sedan 1.6 TDI Sport Line Dizel Otomatik 19000 KM">
    </a>
    <div class="inventroy-content">
      <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2016-audi-a3-a3-sedan-1-6-tdi-sport-line-dizel-otomatik-beyaz-379" title="2016 Audi A3İncele">
        <h3>Audi A3</h3>
        <span>2016</span>
        <span>Dizel</span>
        <span>Otomatik</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- Row /- -->
<!-- Row -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 inventroy-box">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Car" class="item">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2013-hyundai-i30-1-6-crdi-style-dizel-otomatik-beyaz-378" title="2013 Hyundai i30İncele">
        <img itemprop="image" src="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/otogallery/store_logos/thumb/5229/_MG_0208.jpg?1523106439" alt="sahibinden satılık araba 2013 Hyundai i30 1.6 CRDi Style Dizel Otomatik 42840 KM">
    </a>
    <div class="inventroy-content">
      <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2013-hyundai-i30-1-6-crdi-style-dizel-otomatik-beyaz-378" title="2013 Hyundai i30İncele">
        <h3>Hyundai i30</h3>
        <span>2013</span>
        <span>Dizel</span>
        <span>Otomatik</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- Row /- -->
<!-- Row -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 inventroy-box">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Car" class="item">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2017-peugeot-3008-1-6-bluehdi-allure-dizel-otomatik-kirmizi-373" title="2017 Peugeot 3008İncele">
        <img itemprop="image" src="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/otogallery/store_logos/thumb/5199/_MG_0981.jpg?1517238228" alt="sahibinden satılık araba 2017 Peugeot 3008 1.6 BlueHDi Allure Dizel Otomatik 8000 KM">
    </a>
    <div class="inventroy-content">
      <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2017-peugeot-3008-1-6-bluehdi-allure-dizel-otomatik-kirmizi-373" title="2017 Peugeot 3008İncele">
        <h3>Peugeot 3008</h3>
        <span>2017</span>
        <span>Dizel</span>
        <span>Otomatik</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- Row /- -->
<!-- Row -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 inventroy-box">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Car" class="item">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2014-citroen-c-elysee-1-6-hdi-attraction-dizel-manuel-beyaz-376" title="2014 Citroen C-Elyseeİncele">
        <img itemprop="image" src="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/otogallery/store_logos/thumb/4534/_MG_0133.jpg?1506524742" alt="sahibinden satılık araba 2014 Citroen C-Elysee 1.6 HDi Attraction Dizel Manuel 117220 KM">
    </a>
    <div class="inventroy-content">
      <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2014-citroen-c-elysee-1-6-hdi-attraction-dizel-manuel-beyaz-376" title="2014 Citroen C-Elyseeİncele">
        <h3>Citroen C-Elysee</h3>
        <span>2014</span>
        <span>Dizel</span>
        <span>Manuel</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- Row /- -->
<!-- Row -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 inventroy-box">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Car" class="item">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2015-skoda-octavia-1-6-tdi-style-cr-dizel-otomatik-beyaz-374" title="2015 Skoda Octaviaİncele">
        <img itemprop="image" src="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/otogallery/store_logos/thumb/5208/_MG_0966.jpg?1517238488" alt="sahibinden satılık araba 2015 Skoda Octavia 1.6 TDI Style CR Dizel Otomatik 53000 KM">
    </a>
    <div class="inventroy-content">
      <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2015-skoda-octavia-1-6-tdi-style-cr-dizel-otomatik-beyaz-374" title="2015 Skoda Octaviaİncele">
        <h3>Skoda Octavia</h3>
        <span>2015</span>
        <span>Dizel</span>
        <span>Otomatik</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- Row /- -->
<!-- Row -->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 inventroy-box">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Car" class="item">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2015-skoda-octavia-1-6-tdi-style-cr-dizel-otomatik-siyah-372" title="2015 Skoda Octaviaİncele">
        <img itemprop="image" src="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/otogallery/store_logos/thumb/5183/_MG_0956.jpg?1517237745" alt="sahibinden satılık araba 2015 Skoda Octavia 1.6 TDI Style CR Dizel Otomatik 73000 KM">
    </a>
    <div class="inventroy-content">
      <a itemprop="url" href="/ikinci-el/2015-skoda-octavia-1-6-tdi-style-cr-dizel-otomatik-siyah-372" title="2015 Skoda Octaviaİncele">
        <h3>Skoda Octavia</h3>
        <span>2015</span>
        <span>Dizel</span>
        <span>Otomatik</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- Row /- -->
```

```
.inventroy-box {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Can you please guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try setting the image width to 100%

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: added html & css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bootstrap classes to work, they must be contained inside a `<div>` with a class of `row`. Example here:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because of the irregular height of images or content. 
I think you want something like this:
https://prnt.sc/j302vm
Let's just say you are using this code.

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
</div>
</div>
```

So you nedd to Apply clear both properties at the first div of right hand side.

So apply this css:

```
    @media(min-width: 992px){
    .col-md-4:nth-of-type(3n+1){
    clear:both;
    }
  }
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:991px){
     .col-sm-6:nth-of-type(2n+1){
        clear:both;
        }
    }
```